# shiftkey checklist doesn't work in XMLHttpsRequest

Tags: php, html, xmlhttprequest

I've created code, I have several checkboxes, I also use XMLHttpsRequest, I want to check all at once from top to bottom using the shiftkey on the keyboard. The condition is that if it hasn't been checked, then check, on the contrary, if it has been checked, then uncheck, but all of them must be checked by pressing the shift key on the keyboard, so they won't be checked one by one anymore.

Well, all of that goes smoothly if I don't use XMLHttpsRequest, but if I use XMLHttpsRequest it can only be checked one by one. What's the solution?

the output is like this:

[image]

File 1 (z1.php):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/to/img/bqicon.png"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            var coba = document.getElementById("coba");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/to/z1ajax.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
                    coba.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            var v="onload=yes";
            xhr.send(v);
        }
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $chkboxestb=$('.chkboxtb');
            var lastChecked=null;
            $chkboxestb.click(function(e){
                if(!lastChecked){
                    lastChecked=this;
                    return;
                }
                if(e.shiftKey){
                    var start=$chkboxestb.index(this);
                    var end=$chkboxestb.index(lastChecked);
                    $chkboxestb.slice(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end)+ 1).prop('checked',e.target.checked);
                }
                lastChecked = this;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='coba'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2 (z1ajax.php):

```
<?php
    include('bqcon.php');
    
    $onload=isset($_REQUEST['onload'])?$_REQUEST['onload']:null;
    if($onload=='yes'){
        $q=$pdo->query("SELECT ai FROM t_trx");
        while($f=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $ai=$f->ai;
            echo "
                <center>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='' class='chkboxtb' value='$ai' onchange='ochtb(this)'><br>
                </center>
            ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using the "Shift-key", why not adding a "check all button" and an "un-check all" button ?

Comment: because sometimes not everything is checked, we just check what we want